# Fill a shape with points

Tags: java, shapes, fill

I try to draw a leaf looking thing on the screen, and try to fill it with a color. It's like drawing a circle, the difference is, that it's only 270 degrees, and the radius starts from 0 to 100. I first draw the left side, and on each degree I fill the inside. At the end I draw the right side.
Here is to code, maybe it's easier to understand:

```
canvas = new BufferedImage(SIZE, SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Color black = new Color(0,0,0);
Color green = new Color(0,130,0);
double j = 0.0; // radius
double max = 100.0; // max radius

for (int i = 0; i < 135; i++) { // left side (270 degree / 2)
    j += max / 135.0; 

    // x, y coordinate
    int x = (int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)) * j);
    int y = (int)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * j);

    // draw a circle like thing with radius j
    for (int l = i; l < 135 + (135 - i); l++) {
        int ix = (int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(l)) * j);
        int iy = (int)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(l)) * j);

        canvas.setRGB(ix + 256, iy + 256, green.getRGB());
    }

    canvas.setRGB(x + 256, y + 256, black.getRGB());
}

// draw the right side
for (int i = 135; i < 270; i++) {
    j -= max / 135.0;

    int x = (int)(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)) * j);
    int y = (int)(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)) * j);

    canvas.setRGB(x + 256, y + 256, black.getRGB());
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see, where the radius is bigger, the leaf is not filled completely.
If I change `i to 1350`, then divide it with 10 where I calculate `x, y`, then it's filled, but it's much slower. Is there a better way to properly fill my shape?
Later I also would like to fill my shape with a gradient, so from green to a darker green, then back to green. With my method this is easy, but super slow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure: I assume that you are **not** allowed to make this task trivial by just calling  `canvas.getGraphics()`, and using all the infrastructure that is provided by the `Graphics` class...?

Comment: There are no restrictions, I only try things out, as I never worked with Java graphics before. The only thing is, that I would like to use the setRGB method, and not just drawing lines and arcs.

Comment: When the reason behind using `setRGB` is that you want your painting to be contained in a `BufferedImage`, then it may be worth mentioning that you can paint lines and arcs and filled shapes *into* an image, but maybe you already know that, and there are other reasons for not doing this.

Comment: Yes, I know. First I only wanted to paint the window with different colors each pixel, and later I decided to draw circle and other things with some math involved in it, and now this fill the shape.

Comment: Sorry, but I still think that the intention is unclear. At the moment, you are just setting points based on some rule that coincidentally happens to look like a leaf. A flood fill will not help you, because you don't have a closed border. If you want to fill arbitrary shapes (with manual `setRGB` calls) then the usual approach would be a Scanline Algorithm ( http://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/ComputerGraphics/PolygonFilling.html ), but this is really not trivial to implement - particularly when you have no *representation* of the border of the polygon to be filled.

Comment: Yes, I know, I plan to create this shape to have a closed border.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for you the best solution is to use a flood fill algorithm, it's easy to implement in Java and efficient in your case, like you have a simple shape.

Here is a wikipedia article that is really complet : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple suggestion: Instead of drawing the leaf, just put the points that create the outline into an array. The array should run from `xMin` (smallest X coordiate of the leaf outline) to `xMax`. Each element is two ints: `yMin` and `yMax`.

After rendering all the points, you can just draw vertical lines to fill the space between `yMin`/`yMax` for each X coordinate.

If you have gaps in the array, fill them by interpolating between the neighboring points.

An alternative would be to sort the points clockwise or counter-clockwise and use them as the outline for a polygon.

Comment: I think I will try it with the array. It sounds pretty easy, and looks much faster, than my solution.

Comment: Good luck; note that it sounds easier than it looks. As a start, I suggest to begin with `xMin = 0` and `xMax = width of screen` to make your life easier. You can then optimize the algorithm later.